# Setting different container type for Yii2 BS layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

Does anyone know how to change the container layout in Yii2 on only certain pages.

Naturally, if I change the container div to 'container-fluid' instead of the default 'container' in the site css, it will be site wide change.  But I only want to use it on 1 or 2 specific views, how can I target particular views for this container div ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout suitable for you in the directory views\ layouts and call it in your action by entering

```
 $ this-> layout = 'yourLayout';
  return $ this-> render ('yourForm', [
       'model' => $ yourModel,

 ]);
```

For example the layout main use

```
    <div class='container'>
                ......>
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
```

the layout wide use no container for a window wide page

```
    <div >
                ......>
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For others that might like to do the same, here are steps that work for me:

I copied /layouts/main.php to /layouts/main-fluid.php

In main-fluid.php, simply one change:

```
<div class="container">
```

to

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Within the action that I need the 'fluid' layout, simply add:

```
$this->layout = 'main-fluid';
```

before the call to render view.